# Not able to run vnstat unless as root in debian 7

Tags: debian, interface

So, I need to run this command:

```
vnstat -tr 2
```

But as a user I just created, not as root, as root it works fine, but as a regular user I get this:

```
Error: Unable to get interface "eth0" statistics.
Error: Interface "eth0" not available, exiting.
```

On Debian 6 there wasn't this restriction, how do I remove it? Sounds like a permissions problem.

Comment: Just a thought. Does adding `/sbin/` to your `PATH` help?

Answer (score 0):

On my server, `vnstat` reads from `/proc/net/dev` when I use the `-tr` parameter:

```
iserv ~ # strace -e trace=file vnstat -tr 2
execve("/usr/bin/vnstat", ["vnstat", "-tr", "2"], [/* 46 vars */]) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/root/.vnstatrc", O_RDONLY)       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/vnstat.conf", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/proc/net/dev", O_RDONLY)         = 3
Sampling eth0 (2 seconds average)...open("/proc/net/dev", O_RDONLY)         =12 packets sampled in 2 seconds     
Traffic average for eth0

      rx            4 kbit/s             4 packets/s
      tx            0 kbit/s             1 packets/s
```

I'd suggest that you check you `/proc/net/dev` permissions. On Debian 6.0.7, it looks like this:

```
iserv ~ # ll /proc/net/dev
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 14. Sep 14:19 /proc/net/dev
```